# Integral closure exercise from Reid's Undergraduate Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $A=k[X]$ and $f\in A$; then set $B=k[X,Y]/(Y^2-f)$. Find the necessary and sufficient condition that $f$ must satisfy in order for $B$ to be an integral domain. Assume this holds, and write $K$ for the field of fractions of $B$, that is $K=k(X)(\sqrt f)$. For any $\alpha \in K$, write down a polynomial $h(t)\in A[T]$ such that $h(\alpha)=0$. Show that $B$ is normal if and only if $f$ has no square factors. If $B$ is not normal show how to obtain its normalisation in terms of $f$.

For the first part, $(Y^2-f)$ should be a prime ideal, it cannot be $(0)$ since $f \in A$. So, there are two other options for this ideal but I could not find a condition for $f$. For the rest I have some ideas but could not obtain anything useful. Also, there is a hint provided: Write $\alpha=a+b\sqrt f$, where $a,b \in K(X)$.

Comment: The hint suggests that something interesting happens when $\sqrt{f} \in A$.  Can you describe what interesting thing that is?

Comment: I cannot see the connection. $f$ is given and $f$ is rarely a perfect square so $\sqrt f$ is not in $A$ in general. If it is, then $\alpha$ becomes a polynomial in $k(X)$, the field of fractions of $k[X]$. What should I conclude? Maybe I can use the fact that if $\alpha$ is a root of $h$, then, in fact, $\alpha \in A$. But I think that is true only if $h$ is monic. I am quite confused actually :) If I knew $\alpha$ were integral over $A$, then $h$ would certainly exists but I doubt that it is true.

Comment: Notice that in a quotient, we declare the "divisor" to be zero.  In this case, "We announce that $Y^2 - f$ is henceforth zero, with all the algebraic consequences that follow therefrom."  Now, if $f$ happens to be a square, what (high school algebra) interesting thing happens in $Y^2 - f$, a thing we have declared is zero?

Comment: It can be factored, therefore it cannot be a prime.

Comment: Perhaps more directly: then $0$ factors.